# How to solve devtools::check() NOTE on Non standard evaluation of foreach iterator when writing R packages?

Tags: r, foreach, package, devtools, non-standard-evaluation

I'm finishing up writing a package to submit to CRAN and I'm working on purging all of the NOTEs in devtools::check(). Currently I only have a note on non-standard evaluation left to figure out, specifically:

```
no visible binding for global variable ‘i’
```

which seems to be related to my use of `foreach()` in the package where `i` is the foreach iterator. What is the standard evaluation solution to the non-standard evaluation iterator i?

My first idea was to substitute `i` for `.data$i` as you would when replacing non-standard evaluation when programming with `dplyr`, but this did not work. I could use `utils::globalVariables()` but this feels like cheating (plus does not seems safe for a variable name as generic as `i`)

Comment: "plus does not seems safe for a variable name as generic as i" I assume the loop is inside a closure. You could assign `i <- "placeholder"` before the loop (and do `rm(i)` after the loop). This assumes you don't need `i` elsewhere inside the closure. It might be preferable to use a different (less common) name for the `foreach` iterator.